# Cannot connect to GRPC service on Linux computer

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, grpc, opensuse

I have written a GRPC .NET Core Worker service that acts as a server and a .NET Core console application that acts as the GRPC client. Both follow the tutorials that use the helloworld.proto files, but I extended them so that the server can be on one computer and the client on another.

The server is as follows:

```
class GreeterImpl : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    // Server side handler of the SayHello RPC
    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply { Message = "Hello " + request.Name });
    }
}

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    private const int PORT = 5221;
    private Server m_Server;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting grpc...");
        _logger.LogInformation("Local machine name: {computer}, Port: {port}", Environment.MachineName, PORT);
        m_Server = new Server
        {
            Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort(Environment.MachineName, PORT, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };
        m_Server.Start();

        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Shutting down...");
        m_Server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();

        return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The client is as follows:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the server IP address or name:");
            string server = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"The server entered was: {server}");

            Channel channel = new Channel(string.Format("{0}:5221", server), ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            string user = "you";

            var reply = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = user });
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);

            channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

They are using port 5221 in this case to connect.

I have successfully run the program:

- The server on a Windows computer, the client on a different Windows computer.
- The server on a Windows computer, the client on a opensuse linux computer.
- The server and client on the same opensuse linux computer.

The configuration that I cannot get to work is when the server is running on the opensuse linux computer and the client is on a Windows computer. I get the error:
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="failed to connect to all addresses"). That happens on the Windows computer running the client. The server, running on opensuse linux is not affected.

The linux and Windows computer can ping each other by name and ip address. The port 5221 is open on the linux computer. I am not a linux guru and I think it is some networking issue on that computer while running the server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure that port 5221 is open to connections on the linux machine? Try running "test-netconnection {host} -port 5221" to test. If not, you'll need to configure the firewall.

Comment: @TylerE Did you finally manage to run your program with linux being a server and windows a client?

Comment: @tube-builder No, I could never figure it out and gave up on it.

Comment: @TylerE In case you still need it, please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096014/grpc-cannot-connect-to-a-linux-service-from-a-windows-client Thanks to the unix/linux part of stack exchange I have now successfully run my client on Windows while having service running on Linux. Perhaps will give you some thoughts as well.